# What are the Pros and Cons of Gnome Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Could Someone Briefly Explain to me about What is the Advantages and Disadvantages of Gnome Sort.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome sort always performs not faster, than an insertion sort, so it is not the best sort for small arrays. And for big arrays, it is absolutely useless, because it is O(n<sup>2</sup>), and it is dominated by O(n log n) sorts. There are no reasonable cases where you should use gnome sort. Insertion sort can work for small arrays (under 30 elements I suppose, but it really depends on constant factors), and for bigger arrays quick sort or merge sort are preferred.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude ! :) this answer is perfect